# Hibernate, Gilead and GWT

Tags: gwt, gilead

I'm experiencing some problems with GWT and Gilead/Hibernate

I did my code according to the tutorial but it fails with 
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'ru.atamur.entity.UserEntity_gilead_15' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = ru.atamur.entity.UserEntity_gilead_15@133fa82

Looking at the source code I can see that Gilead transformed my UserEntity into UserEntity_gilead_15 inside GileadRPCHelper.parseReturnValue(returnValue, _beanManager)

I can see that this was deliberately done by ProxyClassMapper (I'm trying to use proxy mode), so I was wondering where Gilead was expecting to tell GWT Serilization mechanism about this new proxy class it introduced ...

Comment: Hi, what was the fix for this issue ?? I have the same problem, and nothing seems to be working (Ive implemented isSerializable as well.)

Comment: just using another type of gilead support: i'm extending LightEntity and it works fine (altho is not pretty if you ask me)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code ?

before that I want to say that **SerializationException** is thrown when your class doesn't implement **isSerializable** interface that you send it to the server.

Every class that you send to the server should implement **isSerializable** interface

Comment: my class implements java.io.Serializable, I haven't seen any docs that say that I need isSerializable (at least not since gwt 1.5)

Comment: have a look at this http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=131 .GWT RPC system does support limited use of java.io.Serializable. java.io.Serializable is not the same as isSerializable interface

Comment: I do know about that, look at the date - 2007, this article is outdated and IsSerializable is deprecated y google afaik